# How to only trigger event on element being clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create custom increment / subtract number input arrows

The issue I'm having is how to find a way to only trigger the event on the element being clicked - Currently it's triggering the function on all input fields

EDIT**
Code has been updated as I should mention I am looping through items and each input has a wrapper div with the class ".cart__qty-input"

```js
  var quantityInput = document.querySelectorAll('.cart__qty-input');
  var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.inc_plus');
  var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.inc_minus');

  for (i = 0; i < plusBtn.length; i++) {
    plusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', addQuantity)
  }

  function addQuantity(event) {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    let activeIndex = null;
    // Find Index
    for (index = 0; index < plusBtn.length; index++) {
      if(plusBtn[index] === currentTarget) {
        activeIndex = index;
      }
    }
    var quantityValue = Number(quantityInput[activeIndex].value)
    var newQuantity = quantityValue + 1;
    quantityInput[activeIndex].value = newQuantity;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < minusBtn.length; i++) {
    minusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', minusQuantity)
  }

  function minusQuantity(event) {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    let activeIndex = null;
    // Find Index
    for (index = 0; index < minusBtn.length; index++) {
      if(minusBtn[index] === currentTarget) {
        activeIndex = index;
      }
    }

    var quantityValue = Number(quantityInput[activeIndex].value)
    var newQuantity = quantityValue - 1
    quantityInput[activeIndex].value = newQuantity
  }
```

```html
<div class="cart__qty-input">
<span class="inc_minus">-</span>
<input id="test" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
<span class="inc_plus">+</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="cart__qty-input">
<span class="inc_minus">-</span>
<input id="test" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
<span class="inc_plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current issue is that you have not implemented a logc to pick which is the row against which the +/- button has been clicked.

I have done that in the following way.

1. Select the target node against which the +/- button has been clicked.
2. Parse through the array of the +/- buttons to find the index.
3. Once the index has been found, update the input corresponding to that index only.

Hope this is helpful

```html
<div class="cart__qty-input">
  <span class="inc_minus">-</span>
  <input id="test" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
  <span class="inc_plus">+</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="cart__qty-input">
  <span class="inc_minus">-</span>
  <input id="test" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
  <span class="inc_plus">+</span>
</div>

<script>
  var quantityInput = document.querySelectorAll('.cart__qty-input input.cart__qty-input');
  var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.inc_plus');
  var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.inc_minus');

  for (i = 0; i < plusBtn.length; i++) {
    plusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', addQuantity)
  }

  function addQuantity(event) {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    let activeIndex = null;
    // Find Index
    for (index = 0; index < plusBtn.length; index++) {
      if (plusBtn[index] === currentTarget) {
        activeIndex = index;
      }
    }
    var quantityValue = Number(quantityInput[activeIndex].value)
    var newQuantity = quantityValue + 1;
    quantityInput[activeIndex].value = newQuantity;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < minusBtn.length; i++) {
    minusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', minusQuantity)
  }

  function minusQuantity(event) {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    let activeIndex = null;
    // Find Index
    for (index = 0; index < minusBtn.length; index++) {
      if (minusBtn[index] === currentTarget) {
        activeIndex = index;
      }
    }

    var quantityValue = Number(quantityInput[activeIndex].value)
    var newQuantity = quantityValue - 1
    quantityInput[activeIndex].value = newQuantity
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this! I'm hoping you might be able to help with this last last bit - I should of mentioned that each input is in a div with the class .cart__qty-input so currently the code only works on one input. I edited my code snippet to demonstrate

Comment: You just need to update `quantityInput` as `var quantityInput = document.querySelectorAll('.cart__qty-input input.cart__qty-input');` i.e, select element with class `cart__qty-input` first inside that select `input` with class `cart__qty-input`. Updated the answer. This will work for you.

Comment: What if I don't know the number of times that class will be repeated? Because it is inside a loop

Comment: @BurgerSasha if the DOM structure is like a container div - plus icon - input - minus icon and this repeats for n number of times, this solution will work neverthless the count of the repetation.

Comment: I see! I can't work out why I'm getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @BurgerSasha please update the code with the error that is happening